# Portable Hard Drive- partitions

Tags: linux, portable-harddrive

I just got my first portable hard drive (WD Elements SE 500GB USB 2.0) and I guess I'll be using it for quite a while. So, I just wanted to ask whether I should or should not partition the hard drive. Will partitioning make it slower?

Also, I wanted to know if I could install Linux on the portable hard drive. Is it possible and if yes, is it recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, I just wanted to ask whether I should or should not partition the hard drive.

Depends on how you are planning to use it.

> Will partitioning make it slower?

No, partitioning should not slow down the drive.

> Also, I wanted to know if I could install Linux on the portable hard drive. Is it possible...

Yes (although some older computers might be unable to boot from USB).

> ...and if yes, is it recommended?

There is *no difference* between installing Linux to an internal drive and an external one.

Comment: Well, to be fair, there is one pretty large difference: USB 2.0 is quite a bit slower than internal drives, even with rotating media.  Not that it matters a ton after everything is loaded into RAM, but it makes starting up pretty slow.  Now if it was USB _3.0_, that would be another story, but USB 3.0 is still pretty rare on computers.

Comment: @ grawity, Running an OS from USB 2.0 is dog slow, you did say "installing" though, you might do an edit to clarify that statement.